# How can I specify an overloaded operator in a different namespace?

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble with the C++ standard library. The following example does not compile: (note this is cut down to make a minimal example so does not make much sense as it is)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace otherns {

class Property {
public:
  const std::string &getName() const { return m_name; }

private:
  std::string m_name;
};
}

bool operator==(const otherns::Property &a, const otherns::Property &b) {
  return a.getName() == b.getName();
}

/* Merge, second takes priority */
std::vector<otherns::Property>
merge_props(const std::vector<otherns::Property> &xs,
            const std::vector<otherns::Property> &ys) {
  std::vector<otherns::Property> ans = ys;
  for (const auto &x : xs) {
    if (std::find(ans.begin(), ans.end(), x) == ans.end()) {
      ans.push_back(x);
    }
  }
  return ans;
}
```

The error is "binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'otherns::Property' (or there is no acceptable conversion)" which occurs somewhere in the implementation of `std::find`. This is with MSVC but I also tried with clang and gcc, with a similar result.

The following code does work:

```
std::vector<otherns::Property>
merge_props(const std::vector<otherns::Property> &xs,
            const std::vector<otherns::Property> &ys) {
  std::vector<otherns::Property> ans = ys;
  for (const auto &x : xs) {
    if (std::find_if(ans.begin(), ans.end(), [&x](const otherns::Property &y) {
          return x == y;
        }) == ans.end()) {
      ans.push_back(x);
    }
  }
  return ans;
}
```

I suppose this is something to do with ADL/Koenig lookup but I don't really understand why my `operator==` is not found. what's the best solution if I want to use the first, simpler form of the `find` function?

In reality the `otherns` comes from a header for a 3rd party library so I can't put my operator into that header.

Comment: It's not found because argument dependent lookup only looks in [*"The innermost enclosing namespaces in the classes added to the set*"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). Since your operator is in the global namespace, it is never considered.

Comment: that's why you have to always declare the operators in the same namespace as the class

Comment: The library you use either purposefully tries to disallow ADL, or the writers are guilty of the sin of omission.

Comment: I had looked at the page linked by @StoryTeller; I understood the para starting  "First, the argument-dependent lookup is not considered if the lookup set produced by usual unqualified lookup contains any of the following: " to mean that my operator would be found by "Unqualified lookup" (also, I think omission rather than purposefully disallowing)

Comment: @PeterHull - No it won't. Not inside template instantiations (dependent names are the problem here). Keep reading the page I linked. The problem is that the unqualified lookup is performed at the point of the template *definition*. Not the point of instantiation.

Comment: OK, got it I think, in the [lookup rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#Lookup_rules). But what would you do about it? Just use the form with the lambda?

Comment: @Alex - You don't have to. That's the whole purpose of ADL. String literals aren't subject to ADL since they don't accept class types.

Comment: @PeterHull - The lambda is the only viable solution in my opinion. An inconvenience for sure. Perhaps contacting the library maintainers and reporting this could help future users (including yourself if you keep using the library in future projects).

Comment: @StoryTeller interesting. will read, but it looks you are right. Thanks!

Comment: I will go with the lambda as suggested. My `operator==` does not implement what would be considered to be equality (the actual class `Property` has more data members than just the name), so I what I did was a bit of a cheat/hack anyway. I don't think the library should be modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules are quite complicated, and I myself don't fully grasp them, but let's see if we can make head or tails of them (I think we can):

```
namespace nx {
struct X {};
}

namespace ns {    
auto foo(nx::X x1, nx::X x2) { return x1 == x2; }
// error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'nx::X' and 'nx::X')
}

auto operator==(nx::X, nx::X) { return true; }

auto global_foo()
{
  return ns::foo(nx::X{}, nx::X{}); 
}
```

This isn't found for a simple reason: `operator==` is not declared before its use. Nothing to to with ADL yet. So far so good. We understand that. Let's fix it:

```
namespace nx {
struct X {};
}

auto operator==(nx::X, nx::X) { return true; }

namespace ns {
auto foo(nx::X x1, nx::X x2) { return x1 == x2; }
}

auto global_foo()
{
  return ns::foo(nx::X{}, nx::X{}); 
}
```

Does this work? Yes, it does, it compiles and calls our `operator==`. Is this the correct solution? **No!**. Because if we add this:

```
namespace nx {
struct X {};
}

auto operator==(nx::X, nx::X) { return true; } // (1)

namespace ns {

template <class T> auto operator==(T, int) { return false; } // (2)

auto foo(nx::X x1, nx::X x2) { return x1 == x2; }
// error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'nx::X' and 'nx::X')
}

auto global_foo()
{
  return ns::foo(nx::X{}, nx::X{});
}
```

Then (2) in ns hides (1) in global namespace, even if (1) would be a better fit. This is called **name hiding** and - again - doesn't involve ADL in any way.

Even worse:

```
namespace nx {
struct X {};
}

auto operator==(nx::X, nx::X) { return true; } // (1)

namespace ns {

template <class T> auto operator==(T, T) { return false; } // (2)

auto foo(nx::X x1, nx::X x2) { return x1 == x2; } // calls (2)
}

auto global_foo()
{
  return ns::foo(nx::X{}, nx::X{}); 
}
```

Would compile and silently calls `(2)` instead of our operator `(1)`.

For a real world context think of `namespace ns` as namespace `std` and
any operator declared inside `std`. And you've got the situation in your post.

The correct solution is:

```
namespace nx {
struct X {};
auto operator==(nx::X, nx::X) { return true; } // (1)
}

namespace ns {

template <class T> auto operator==(T, T) { return false; } // (2)

auto foo(nx::X x1, nx::X x2) { return x1 == x2; } // calls (1)
}

auto global_foo()
{
  return ns::foo(nx::X{}, nx::X{}); 
}
```

What happens here is that ADL kicks in and brings `(1)` from `nx` and now `(1)` is considered alongside `(2)`. But `(1)` is more specialized than `(2)` and so `(1)` is correctly selected.

If you don't have control of `namespace nx` and can't add the operator there, then what I can advise is to use callables instead of relying on operators. E.g instead of `std::find` use `std::find_if` with your own predicate (lambda) where you control exactly which method/operator to call. And when I say "exactly" I mean **exactly**: i.e. `::operator==(x1, x2)` (or whatever namespace you declared them) instead of `x1 == x2`.

---

You can read more on this great article by Herb Sutter [Namespaces & Interface Principle](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill08.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Just declare `operator==` inside the namespace `otherns` (The lookup will find it at namespace scope)

```
namespace otherns {
bool operator==(const otherns::Property &a, const otherns::Property &b) {
  return a.getName() == b.getName();
}
}
```

[Working code](http://ideone.com/ZsDmi3)

You can do it in a separate header of the 3rd party library.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `operator==` in the *global* namespace (perhaps misled by the misindentation).  It won't be found there by argument-dependent lookup.

The operator should be declared in the same namespace as (one of) its arguments:

```
namespace otherns {

    class Property {
    public:
        const std::string &getName() const { return m_name; }

    private:
        std::string m_name;
    };

    bool operator==(const otherns::Property &a, const otherns::Property &b) {
        return a.getName() == b.getName();
    }
}
```

That little change enables your example to compile cleanly.